# Tits indices over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Does every Tits index belong to some semisimple algebraic group defined over the field of rational numbers?

Comment: No. For example, $E^{133}_{8,1}$ does not belong to an algebraic group over a number field. See the tables in the Boulder volume:  J. Tits, Classification of algebraic semisimple groups, Proc. Symp Pure Math vol. 9, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1966, pp. 33–62.